# Find max, second max and min value out of multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with columns length, width, height and I want to  find, out of three columns which is max will become length, second max will become width and min will height.

```
table name dimension

length  width   height
5.60    3.70    0.90
13.50   6.54    3.50
14.33   7.95    3.86
6.42    6.69    7.95
12.00   10.00   9.00
5.60    3.70    3.70
```

i tried case logic and find able to find out the max , min but for second max not getting desired result.

```
select length = case
                    when dimension.[length] >= dimension.width and dimension.[length] >= dimension.height then dimension.[length]
                    when dimension.[width] >= dimension.[length] and dimension.[width] >= dimension.height then dimension.[width]
                    when dimension.[height] >= dimension.[length] and dimension.[height] >= dimension.width then dimension.[height]
                end,
        width = case 
                    when (dimension.[length] <= dimension.width and dimension.[length] >= dimension.height)  then dimension.[length] 
                    when (dimension.[width] <= dimension.[length] and dimension.[width] >= dimension.height) then dimension.[width]
                    when (dimension.[height] <= dimension.[length] and dimension.[height] >= dimension.width )then dimension.[height]
                end,
        height = case 
                    when dimension.[length] <= dimension.width and dimension.length<= dimension.height then dimension.[length]
                    when dimension.[width] <= dimension.[length] and dimension.[width] <= dimension.height then dimension.[width]
                    when dimension.[height] <= dimension.[length] and dimension.[height] <= dimension.width then dimension.[height]
                end

from dimension
```

Second largest values should be correctly displayed while returning the length, width and height.

expected output like this

```
length  width   height
5.60    3.70    0.90
13.50   6.54    3.50
14.33   7.95    3.86
7.95    NULL    6.42
12.00   10.00   9.00
5.60    3.70    3.70
```

but for some case i am getting null value in width columns.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: from table example length - 6.42, width - 6.69 , height - 7.95 i want output  like length - 7.95 , width - 6.69 and height - 6.42 , max value out of three columns will become length and second max will become width and min will become height.

Comment: @suraj, why don't u add your expected output in your question.. it should not be in comments

Comment: Do you want MAX() MIN() and "Second MAX()" from EACH column? Or just one selection of the MAX() MIN() and "Second Max()" from any of the three columns?

Option 1) Max() MIN() SecondMax() of all values in all columns
Option 2) Max() MIN() SecondMax() for each column (3 x 3 results)

Comment: @Richard option 2. Max(), SecondMax(), Min() from each columns. and also have added expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For SQL Server 2012+:**

Another possible approach to get your expected output using `ORDER BY` with `OFFSET` and `FETCH`:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE #Dimensions (
    [length] numeric(10, 2),  
    [width] numeric(10, 2),   
    [height] numeric(10, 2)
)
INSERT INTO #Dimensions
    ([length], [width], [height])
VALUES
    (5.60,    3.70,    0.90),
    (13.50,   6.54,    3.50),
    (14.33,   7.95,    3.86),
    (6.42,    6.69,    7.95),
    (12.00,   10.00,   9.00),
    (5.60,    3.70,    3.70)
```

Statement:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM #Dimensions d
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT 
        [length] = (SELECT N FROM (VALUES (d.[length]), (d.[width]), (d.[height])) v(N) ORDER BY N DESC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY),
        [width] = (SELECT N FROM (VALUES (d.[length]), (d.[width]), (d.[height])) v(N) ORDER BY N DESC OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY),
        [height] = (SELECT N FROM (VALUES (d.[length]), (d.[width]), (d.[height])) v(N) ORDER BY N DESC OFFSET 2 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY)
) c
```

Output:

```
----------------------
length  width   height
----------------------
5.60    3.70    0.90
13.50   6.54    3.50
14.33   7.95    3.86
7.95    6.69    6.42
12.00   10.00   9.00
5.60    3.70    3.70
```

**For SQL Server 2008+:**

When `ORDER BY` with `OFFSET` and `FETCH` is not supported, approach using `ROW_NUMBER()` is also a solution:

```
SELECT 
    [length] = c1.N,
    [width] = c2.N,
    [height] = c3.N
FROM #Dimensions d
CROSS APPLY (SELECT N, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY N DESC) AS RN FROM (VALUES (d.[length]), (d.[width]), (d.[height])) v(N)) c1
CROSS APPLY (SELECT N, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY N DESC) AS RN FROM (VALUES (d.[length]), (d.[width]), (d.[height])) v(N)) c2
CROSS APPLY (SELECT N, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY N DESC) AS RN FROM (VALUES (d.[length]), (d.[width]), (d.[height])) v(N)) c3
WHERE (c1.RN = 1) AND (c2.RN = 2) AND (c3.RN = 3)
```

Comment: this is fine for sql server 2012 and above . what about sql server 2008 R2?

Comment: Thanks !! Really nice solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this works for you:

```
select
    length = (select max(v) from (values (length), (width), (height)) as t(v)),
    width = (select (sum(v) - max(v) - min(v)) from (values (length), (width), (height)) as t(v)),
    height = (select min(v) from (values (length), (width), (height)) as t(v))
from dimension
```

Answer (score 0):

--------Logic------------------------
Group it vertically through key column the  apply aggregation Logic

---

```
select * from sample;

 length | width | height 

 6 |     4 |      1
14 |     7 |      4
---------------------------------
This query been tried in Postgres   (U can use rownum in oracle in place of grpno)

with basedata as  (select floor(random()*100) grpno,length,width ,height from sample)  
select max(measurmnt) as length,min(measurmnt) height,sum(measurmnt)-( max(measurmnt)+min(measurmnt)) as width from 
 ( select grpno,length measurmnt from basedata union all  
         select grpno,width from basedata  union all 
 select grpno,height from basedata order by 1
) as outerq
group by grpno;
 length | height | width 
--------+--------+-------
      6 |      1 |     4
     14 |      4 |     7
```